# Fastest way to destroy a tree structure in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have some code in VB6 which creates a moderately-large tree structure (a few thousand nodes).  Performance is adequate except when destroying the last reference to a tree.  That can sometimes take a second or more.  I've tried killing all the internal references within each node before deleting the node itself, but that doesn't seem to help.  Is there some trick to speed up whatever vb6 is doing with its reference counters?  There seems to be a significant N^2 aspect to the performance.

Incidentally, I know VB6 is obsolescent, but I have someone complaining about this code which I wrote quite some time ago but which is still in use.

BTW, the tree is not a binary tree, but instead allows each node to have an arbitrary number of children, held in a Collection and accessed by name (so one node might be TheTree!This!That!TheOtherThing!Whatever, aka TheTree("This")("That")("TheOtherThing")("Whatever")).

Comment: Some of this may not be the Collection nodes, but the type(s) of items you're using at the "leaves" of the tree.  Objects as leaves add a lot of weight and deallocation time.

Comment: As I recall. VB6 is a "user friendly" veneer over COM, so you'll have all that reference counting with extra treacle on top. You have an inherent problem that was later addressed with garbage collection. They've taken thier time to complain, maybe they should upgrade to the contemporary version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB6 collection objects are notorious for being slow to release their contents, esp when there's a lot of contained references.

You might try a replacement collection, like [this](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3309).  There's a number of other replacement Collections for VB6 that should be essentially drop in compatible.

You might also want to read up on Bruce Mckinney's [take](http://brucem.mystarband.net/mckinney2b.htm) on the collection object.

EDIT: More Bruce McKinney info [here](http://vb.mvps.org/hardweb/mckinney.htm)

Comment: Thanks for writing.  Any idea what's causing the Collection to be so slow to release objects, or what might be done to speed it up?  The code works, and has been in use for many years, so I'm not eager to make any major overhaul.  I was wondering whether there might be some trick to improve deletion speed.  One trick I tried was to have the object's destructor add to a list all the items in the Collection, destroy the reference to the collection, and then at some later time remove the items from the list.  That sped up the destruction of the first collection, but then...

Comment: ...the destruction of the items in the list was slow.  On the other hand, I think I may have used a Collection to hold the list of objects awaiting deletion; I wonder if perhaps using arrays might work better?

Comment: @Angryhacker. thanks for the edits! that does look a little better with the embedded links like that.

Comment: Odd. Another thing to look at is is there any peculiar code going on in the terminate event for those objects contained in the collection? that could be the culprit and not the collection itself. If there's much of any code in the terminate, it could definitely have an effect on release speed.

Comment: @drventure: I've experimented with various things.  With no code in the "terminate" event, killing the last reference to a big collection is very slow.  Code in the terminate event can amortize this time in various ways, but I haven't yet managed to eliminate it.  One idea I just had, though, would be to have the "terminate" event make temporary references to all the leaves, kill the collection that held a reference to them, and then kill off the leaves one by one.  At the time each leaf would die, the only reference would be an array rather than a Collection.

Comment: @drventure: I just figured out how to use the Dictionary object in vb6.  What a HUGE difference!  What the (bleep) is the Collection object doing when it's destroyed such that EACH deletion requires time proportional to the SQUARE of the number of Collection objects!?  Dictionary seems workable with 200,000 interior nodes and 8,000,000 leaf nodes.  The old Collection-based system got doggy with 1% if that.

Comment: I believe (though I've not disassembled anything to prove it yet) the the old collection object rearranged it's contained object references in memory based on some sorting order, each time you delete an item.

Comment: That could be the case, but would only explain the slowness if Collection is sharing some kind of large data structure among all instances.  The slowness when dealing many nested Collection objects would be explained if deletes force objects to be rearranged, but it seems execution time to delete a Collection object is related to the square of the number of Collection objects in the system, even if they're all "independent".

Comment: The link to Bruce Mckinney's article, is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but I doubt you'll be able to reduce the amount of time that it takes to terminate the object tree.  10 years ago or so I co-developed [SQL Accord](http://sqleffects.com/) in VB6 -- an application that did database comparisons.  So as you can imagine you are holding thousands of objects in memory (e.g. table/view/sproc/etc definitions) to be able to quickly compare them.

The initial design of holding these objects in collections fell on the floor due to the issues that the OP brought up.  The culprit is the COM garbage collection scheme - it needs to clean up the moment you set the object to Nothing/Null and then most likely it needs to defrag the memory space - that takes time.

My solution (painful at the time) was to convert all objects into TYPE structures and convert collections into arrays of types.  Then I built manager objects to deal with the arrays/types/etc...

Even though the code smells when you look at it - I got a 10x performance increase out of it.  Why?  Because TYPE structures go on the stack, while objects go on the heap, where it is much more expensive to dispose of them.

Answer (score 1):

Curland's [Advanced Visual Basic](http://www.powervb.com/) explains how to create lightweight COM objects and how to organize instances of these in large systems of objects that use custom memory manager. The benefit is basicly that you can allocate a large single (or several but not many) chunk of memory to store all the instances that can be released in one go. This reduces tear down time to zero.

Lightweight objects are structs (`Type`s in VB6) wrapped in COM interfaces so to look like regular COM objects. Arrays of UDTs are allocated and destroyed very fast as these occupy a single chunk of memory.

Comment: What would you think of the idea of copying all of the nested items within a collection to an array, then ditching the collection (which won't trigger any nested deletes since all the items that were in the collection will have a live reference) and then ditching the array (the items of which will no longer be attached to the large tree)?

Comment: If by "ditching" the collection you mean releasing it (setting to nothing) then you can simply cache a reference to it somewhere and release it later when the user is idle. This will delay objects tear down too and will improve perceived speed but will not optimize real tear down process.

Comment: Setting a single collection to nothing can take well over a second.  If nothing else, having one of my object's terminate routine add it to a list of objects needing destruction, and then having an idle handler which takes an item from the list, adds its children to the list, and then abandons the item, allows user interaction to continue while the item is deleted.  When I was trying that, though, I kept things pending deletion in a Collection; I wonder if using an array would improve performance?